# CakePHP 3 hasMany will not pass parent ID to associated children

Tags: cakephp-3.0

```
     /* ShootsTable.php Meta Table */ 

       public function initialize(array $config)
        {
            $this->table('shoots');
            $this->displayField('title');
            $this->primaryKey('id');
            $this->hasMany('ShootMeta');
        }


    /* ShootMetaTable.php Meta Table */

     public function initialize(array $config)
        {
            $this->table('shoot_meta');
            $this->displayField('id');
            $this->primaryKey('id');
            $this->belongsTo('Shoots');
        }
        public function buildRules(RulesChecker $rules)
         {
            $rules->add($rules->existsIn(['shoots_id'], 'Shoots'));
            return $rules;
         }

 /* Shoots.php Controller */

public function add()
    {
        $shoot = $this->Shoots->newEntity(null);
        if ($this->request->is('post')) {
            $this->Shoots->patchEntity($shoot, $this->request->data,[
                'associated' => ['ShootMeta']
            ]);
            $shoot->set('created_by', 1);
            debug($shoot);
            if ($this->Shoots->save($shoot,['associated' => ['ShootMeta']])) {
                $this->Flash->success('The shoot has been saved.');
               // return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
            } else {
                $this->Flash->error('The shoot could not be saved. Please, try again.');
            }
        }
        $this->set(compact('shoot'));
        $this->set('_serialize', ['shoot']);
    }

 /* Add.ctp Template */

<div class="shoots form large-10 medium-9 columns">
    <?= $this->Form->create($shoot); ?>
    <fieldset>
        <legend><?= __('Add Shoot') ?></legend>
        <?php
            echo $this->Form->input('title');
            echo $this->Form->input('content');
            echo $this->Form->input('datetime', ['label' => 'Date/Time Of Shoot']);

            echo $this->Form->input('shoot_meta.0.meta_key', ['type' => 'hidden', 'value' => 'photographer_spaces']);
            echo $this->Form->input('shoot_meta.0.meta_value',['label' => 'Photographer Spaces', 'type' => 'number']);
        ?>
    </fieldset>
    <?= $this->Form->button(__('Submit')) ?>
    <?= $this->Form->end() ?>
</div>

/* debug($shoots) output */

object(App\Model\Entity\Shoot) {

    'new' => true,
    'accessible' => [
        'created_by' => true,
        'title' => true,
        'content' => true,
        'datetime' => true,
        'shoot_meta' => true
    ],
    'properties' => [
        'title' => '123',
        'content' => '123',
        'datetime' => object(Cake\I18n\Time) {

            'time' => '2015-03-19T07:04:00+0000',
            'timezone' => 'UTC',
            'fixedNowTime' => false

        },
        'shoot_meta' => [
            (int) 0 => object(App\Model\Entity\ShootMetum) {

                'new' => true,
                'accessible' => [
                    'shoots_id' => true,
                    'meta_key' => true,
                    'meta_value' => true,
                    'shoot' => true
                ],
                'properties' => [
                    'meta_key' => 'photographer_spaces',
                    'meta_value' => '123'
                ],
                'dirty' => [
                    'meta_key' => true,
                    'meta_value' => true
                ],
                'original' => [],
                'virtual' => [],
                'errors' => [
                    'shoots_id' => [
                        '_required' => 'This field is required'
                    ]
                ],
                'repository' => 'ShootMeta'

            }
        ],
        'created_by' => (int) 1
    ],
    'dirty' => [
        'title' => true,
        'content' => true,
        'datetime' => true,
        'shoot_meta' => true,
        'created_by' => true
    ],
    'original' => [],
    'virtual' => [],
    'errors' => [],
    'repository' => 'Shoots'

}
```

As you can see, the field `shoots_id` is required, which I would have thought would be automatically passed down (although at this point it hasn't executed any MySQL).

I feel I may have gone about this the wrong way but have spent 2 full days trying to get it right.  One of those days was me trying to work out why after baking it had named a lot of the references to ShootMeta to ShootMetum, I thought it had actually corrupted it.

One of the biggest issues I have is knowing where to use shoot_meta, ShootMeta, shootmeta, shootmetum, ShootMetum etc.  It feels like a bit of a minefield!

/Update

A dump of the save object below.  It is clearly assigning it, it just seems to not be executing it in the SQL?

```
'shoot_meta' => [
            (int) 0 => object(App\Model\Entity\ShootMetum) {

                'new' => false,
                'accessible' => [
                    'shoots_id' => true,
                    'meta_key' => true,
                    'meta_value' => true
                ],
                'properties' => [
                    'meta_key' => 'photographer_spaces',
                    'meta_value' => '123',
                    'shoot_id' => '2',
                    'id' => '3'
                ],
                'dirty' => [],
                'original' => [],
                'virtual' => [],
                'errors' => [],
                'repository' => 'ShootMeta'

            },
```

Comment: English isn't my native language, so bear with me, but is there really an independent word "Meta" which can be used as some kind of substitute for "Metadata"? The next question would be whether "Meta" is really plural ("Metas" anyone?), and whether "Metum" (only ever heard of this in Latin) is the correct singular.

Comment: And I guess your tables not only have table rules, but also validation rules (required), right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it.

It is referring to shoot_id when i debug the save

```
'shoot_meta' => [
            (int) 0 => object(App\Model\Entity\ShootMetum) {
                'new' => false,
                'accessible' => [
                    'shoots_id' => true,
                    'meta_key' => true,
                    'meta_value' => true
                ],
                'properties' => [
                    'meta_key' => 'photographer_spaces',
                    'meta_value' => '123',
                    'shoot_id' => '2',
                    'id' => '3'
                ],
                'dirty' => [],
                'original' => [],
                'virtual' => [],
                'errors' => [],
                'repository' => 'ShootMeta'

            },
```

for some reason it was using the singular name for the association.  Changed in the Shoots.php model.

*From*

```
$this->hasMany('ShootMeta');
```

*To*

```
$this->hasMany('ShootMeta',[
    'foreignKey' => 'shoots_id'
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the validation rule for `shoots_id`. Validation is for data that is posted from the form, and in this case the foreignKey cannot be posted from the Form. You already have rules in your `buildRules()` method for making sure that value is passed before saving, so removing the validation is 100% safe.

Comment: Removing the validation lets it go through, but the shoots_id is not populated.
    INSERT INTO shoot_meta (meta_key, meta_value) VALUES ('photographer_spaces', '123')

Comment: How did you get to `INSERT` if you have a rule in `buildRules()` preventing the save if the column is not present?

Comment: That's what is coming up in the SQL Log, checked the table and it does execute it, putting shoots_id at 0.

Comment: dump of the rules object

[protected] _rules => [
  (int) 0 => object(Closure) {
   
  }
 ]

Answer (score 0):

i have same problem like this to, for now my solution is sending associated data to other function/methode and save it.
eg

**

```
public function add() {
        $kantor = $this->Kantor->newEntity($this->request->data);
        if ($this->request->is('post')) {
            $kantor = $this->Kantor->patchEntity($kantor, $this->request->data);
            $rgndata = $this->request->data['Telpkantor'];
            $this->request->session()->write('rgndata', $rgndata);
            if ($this->Kantor->save($kantor)) {
                $result = $this->Kantor->save($kantor);
                $this->addTelpKantor($rgndata, $result->id);
                $this->Flash->success('The kantor has been saved.');
                return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
            } else {
                $this->Flash->error('The kantor could not be saved. Please, try again.');
            }
        }
        $reffKota = $this->Kantor->ReffKota->find('list', ['limit' => 200]);
        $statusKantor = $this->Kantor->StatusKantor->find('list', ['limit' => 200]);
        $pimpinan = $this->Kantor->Pimpinan->find('list', ['limit' => 200]);
        $jenisTelp = $this->Kantor->Telpkantor->Jenistelp->find('list', ['limit' => 200]);
        $this->set(compact('kantor', 'reffKota', 'statusKantor', 'pimpinan', 'jenisTelp'));
        $this->set('_serialize', ['kantor']);
    }
    public function addTelpKantor($rgndata = null, $kantor_id=null) {
        if (!empty($rgndata[0]['noTelp'])) {
            $this->loadModel('Telpkantor');
            foreach ($rgndata as $rgndata) {
                $rgndata['kantor_id'] =$kantor_id;
                $rgndatasave = $this->Telpkantor->newEntity($rgndata);
                $this->Telpkantor->save($rgndatasave);
            }
        }
    }
```

**